# Bluemix VM cannot connect via ssh

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

Just as my topic states, I cannot to the server via ssh while I can connect to it via horizon.

My area is America.
I have tried to use CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 14.10, both provided by Bluemix.
I use a security group which enable all data (whatever protocol, no matter ipv4 or ipv6).

When I use putty to connect to it, the server just close my connection.

Anyone has an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try ssh from the command line with -v option and paste the output of

ssh -v -i  ibmcloud@

which would show why the connection is being closed.

Comment: Actually it is working now. I think the network was down at the time I send this post because I tried for a long time but still being unable to connect. Now it is working. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

VM instances on both US region and UK one need some time (at least one minute) to have all the network stack fully enabled and routed after VM boot process is completed.
This is why if you try to connect through SSH just after VM booting up, the connection is refused and then it worked few minutes later